# Как узнать пароль root пользователя phpmyadmin в Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: lamp

Как узнать пароль root пользователя phpmyadmin в lamp-server Ubuntu16.04?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте пароль от вашей базы.

Comment: <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
пробовал поменять root sql password по рекомендации <a href="https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/">с сайта </a>use mysql;
 use mysql;
Database changed
и получил ошибку

mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("l") where User='root';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
 </head>